# Azure DevOps batch for Pull requests

Tags: azure-devops

I use `batch: true` for Azure DevOps pipeline's trigger:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

..and it works as expected (next build starts only when previous completed).

By default multiple build are running in parallel:
[image]

I tried:

```
pr:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

..but it fails: 
[image]

How can I do the same for Pull requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batch will only work with CI trigger at the moment.

> Pull request (PR) triggers cause a build to run whenever a pull
>   request is opened with one of the specified target branches, or when
>   changes are pushed to such a pull request.

By default, pipelines triggered by pull requests (PRs) will be canceled if a new commit is pushed to the same PR. You can auto cancel an existing pipeline when a pull request is updated.

This is desirable in most cases since usually you don't want to continue running a pipeline on out-of-date code. If you don't want this behavior, you can add autoCancel: false to your PR trigger.

```
  pr: 
      autoCancel: false
      branches:
      - master
```

More details please kindly refer our official doc here: [Specify events that trigger pipeline builds and releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: I'm encountering this issue. I don't understand why PR batching isn't supported. Multiple PRs on the same repo can trigger the same pipeline at the same time causing potential conflicts. Is there any work-around?